# Learning Angular: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular, and now stuck in an assignment due to an "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')" error. I see this is quite a common error, but I cannot find what I am doing wrong. Hope someone here can help me!

I am trying to add even numbers to the "even" array, and uneven numbers to the "unEven" array. This is where I am getting the error (reading 'push'). I have declared them, and assigned them an empty array; not sure whet else I can do....

My .ts file is as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrl: './game-control.component.css'
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit{
  counter = 0;
  intervalID;
  even: number[]=[];
  unEven: number[]=[];

  onStartGame(){
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.GameStarted,1000)
    }

  onStopGame(){
    clearInterval(this.intervalID)
  }

  GameStarted(){
    this.counter = this.counter +1;
    Number.isInteger(this.counter/2)? this.even.push(this.counter) : this.unEven.push(this.counter);
    console.log('Even numbers logged: '+ this.even);
    console.log('Uneven numbers logged: '+ this.unEven);
  }
  ngOnInit(){}
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you log `this.even` and `this.unEven` before calling `push` inside `GameStarted`? I don't seem to be able to reproduce your problem...

Comment: I was about to post the same as tobifasc. Nothing majorly wrong with the code. Is there any other code related or any other error?

Comment: So when I comment out the entire Number.IsiNteger line (which contains the "push" command, the error is gone. The log then shows: 
Even numbers logged: undefined
Uneven numbers logged: undefined
I guess this makes sense, as the array is empty?

Comment: TIL about `this` in callbacks. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this corrected method:

```
onStartGame(){
  this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.gameStarted(), 1000);
}

gameStarted(){
  this.counter = this.counter + 1;
  Number.isInteger(this.counter / 2) ? this.even.push(this.counter) : this.unEven.push(this.counter);
  console.log('Even numbers logged: ' + this.even);
  console.log('Uneven numbers logged: ' + this.unEven);
}
```

Additionally, it's a good practice to follow the naming conventions in TypeScript/JavaScript. Typically, method names should start with a lowercase letter. So, it would be better to rename `GameStarted` to `gameStarted`.

Comment: Yes! This works!! I'll have to puzzle a bit to see what you've done and why, but at least Im no longer stuck. Txs!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value of `this` in your `GameStarted` method as you are invoking the method via `setInterval(this.GameStarted,1000)` which can change `this`. To preserve `this` value try invoking via arrow functions or use `this.GameStarted.bind(this)` in setInterval

```js
onStartGame(){
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.GameStarted.bind(this), 1000)
    }
```

Comment: Hi James,
When I log this.counter, it gives NaN as value..... So you might be on to something there...
I'm not familiar with arrow functions. 
When I change the onStartGame method to:
 onStartGame(){
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.GameStarted.bind(this).GameStarted,1000)
    }
The counter just doesnt work anymore.